# Generic SQL UPDATE clause suitable for mutliple data types

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

Fairly new to SQL. Say I have a table with field1 of type string (VARCHAR) and field2 of type integer (INTEGER). As I understand it, you're supposed to use `='newValue'` for string fields, and `=newValue` for integer fields (and `=#newValue#` for date fields).

Is there a trick that allows generic construction of the SET clause without needing to know the type of the field being updated in advance?

```
void UpdateDatabase(string field, string oldValue, string newValue)
{
    // Construct without needing work out whether '', ## or (nothing) is required?
    string sqlUpdate = (
        "UPDATE MyTable" +
        " SET " + field + " = " + newValue +
        " WHERE " + field + " = " + oldValue);
    // Execute the statement on the database
}
```

This might be used as follows:

```
UpdateDatabase("field1", "Danger Mouse!", "Mickey Mouse");
UpdateDatabase("field2", "15", "7");
```

Comment: Not really, but you should be using SQL parameters and not concatenating the values into the query string.

Comment: Tag the database you are using. What you intend to do is a llittle dubious but ultimately would be better handled by a sql stored procedure with access to the information_schema tables, not client code.

Comment: I would strongly suggest either separate coding for each table, or using an ORM such as Dapper or Entity Framework. Whatever you do, **use parameters**

Answer (score -1):

Your code will need to be a lot more complex if you want to predetermine the datatypes of the fields you're inserting into.

Most SQL flavours have some kind of catalog, so for example on MS SQL Server you would need do something like:

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'field'
```

For every column you're about to write to, then apply the single-quote or not as per the data type.
There's ways and means of doing this, and depending on how many different fields you want to write at the same time will depend how complex the logic has to be to get the column datatypes.
For a large number of columns ideally you would gather all the column names you're about to write to into a table first, then use that table to query the datatypes

However, in SQL Server you can normally get away with putting single-quotes around everything, even integers and floats. SQL Server will intelligently remove the single quotes as needed.

It looks like you're using MySQL since you're required to put hashes around dates, in which case I am sorry for your loss.

Comment: Actually, I've inherited an old project still using DAO and Microsoft Access 97. Am in the process of updating to ODBC, OleDB or SQL Server.

Comment: Use parameters properly, especially if you have already queried the data types

Comment: ODBC and OLEDB are styles of connection, not databases. Access 97 is among the worst database engines ever devised, I would swap to SQL Server as soon as you are able, then this data type issue goes away, since you can just single-quote everything you insert.